# Array in Python Object Oriented

Tags: python, arrays, object, numpy

I am kind of new in Object Oriented programming. I am reviewing a code and there is a part that I have difficulty to understand. I do appreciate if you can help me.

I have a code in which we have numpy array and then it seems "array" is used as attribute or method for the the numpy array but I am not sure how it does work. Following is the syntax that I have:

> self.PromotionIdData.array()[self.ID,t] = ...

PromotionIdData is a two-dimensional numpy array. 
But I can not generate the similar syntex for myself. here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from array import *
class test:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.price=np.array([10,20,30])
        self.cost=20
        self.volum=2

a=test()
print getattr(a,'price').array[1]
```

But my code does not work. I got the error indicating "array" is not an attribute.

Thanks,

Comment: See the difference between `nparray.array()[i]` and `nparray.array[i]`?

Comment: Could you please give me some references for "nparray.array()[i]"?

Comment: Sorry for writing a wall of text, but please take a moment and read my answer @user3040845

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *test *class has 3 attributes: price, cost and volume.

*Numpy* module, or to simplify, class, has its own attribute array.

*Numpy* and *test* are separate classes, and you're confusing them. In your `__init__` you call the function `np.array()` and you assign the output to `test.price`. Now let's take a minute and think what exactly was assigned to `test.price`. It's nothing more than a numpy array, and `test.price` behaves exactly the same as any other numpy array would. Classes and objects aren't black magic: variables stored there behave in a very intuitive way! This was hard for me to imagine at first too, so I know where you stand. 
One more thing to remember: classes have their own namespaces, which means that `test.var` is independent from `var` and they don't interfere with each other in any way. You'll learn to appreciate namespaces sooner or later ;)

A couple of more examples:

```
def __init__(self):
    dict={'a': 123}
    list=[1,2,3,4]
    var='spam'
var='eggs and spam'

>>>test.dict['a']
123
>>>test.list[2]
3
>>>test.var
spam
>>>var
eggs and spam
```

As to your example of `self.PromotionIdData.array()[self.ID,t] = ...`
That's a bit higher level of object oriented programming. Inside class definitions you can define functions, or rather methods, and call them the way you did in your example. Like so:

```
class test():
    def array(self): #remember to always pass self to a function inside your class
        return [1,2,3,4,5]

>>>t=test()
>>>t.array[2]
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import `array`, as it is a numpy class and you are already importing numpy (and indeed you  call array with `np.array`).

Once you have a numpy array object you can access the elements using square brackets without any additional notes:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print a[1]
```

Also, to access an attribute of your class you only need to use the dot syntax, I think your test should read something like this:

```
print a.price[1]
```

(Edited after the OP clarification)

If you want to be able to call `array()` in your class, you need to define an array method that returns the attribute you want:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.price=np.array([10,20,30])
        self.cost=20
        self.volum=2

    def array(self):
        return self.price
```

then you can do `a.array()[1]` (note that you don't need to explicitly indicate the price attribute anymore). For this type of constructions you might want to take a look at the notions of [getters and setters](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/02/06/getters-and-setters-in-python/)

Comment: Yes, but I want to generate a syntex similar to the code that I am reviewing: PromotionIdData.array()[ID,t]=...

Comment: Edited my reply to address your clarification